# How to add prefix to "/set_camera_info" service?

Tags: ros, camera-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to advertise a camera image+info in order to calibrate it.
I create my info manager like follows :

```
camera_info_manager::CameraInfoManager info_mgr(nh, "webcam");
```

webcam is my camera name. Though, when I start the programme and ask for a "rosservice list" I only get :

```
/set_camera_info
```

with no prefix. What am I missing ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35469/how-to-add-prefix-to-%22/set_camera_info%22-service-?/) by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on ROS Answers with karma: 514 on 2012-06-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [API documentation](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/camera_info_manager/html/classcamera__info__manager_1_1CameraInfoManager.html#a8944fe301b12d38ed33ac6ccb3d9b63b) specifies `nh` to be a `ros::NodeHandle` for the camera's streaming name space. You seem to have passed a node handle for the driver node, instead.

The second (`cname`) parameter has a different purpose. It attempts to identify which physical device the associated calibration describes. For that, a UUID or make, model and serial number [are recommended](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/camera_info_manager/html/classcamera__info__manager_1_1CameraInfoManager.html#_details).

Try something like this:

```
camera_info_manager::CameraInfoManager cinfo(ros::NodeHandle("webcam"));
```

That will advertise `/webcam/set_camera_info`.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on 2012-06-02**:
It works perfectly ! Thank you for all the advices.